# How to connect ODP.Net through a firewall?

Tags: oracle, firewall, odp.net

Apologies for a newbie question, but that's me - new to Oracle.

My client and oracle server are separated by a firewall. A limited set of IP addresses can be routed through this firewall. One routable IP is the address of a SCAN listener, which redirects to oracle servers that have non-routable IPs.

I am able to connect SQL Developer to my database, but not a simple ODP.Net client.

Using wireshark, I see that when SQL Developer connects to the SCAN listener, SCAN replies with a redirect to a random port on the SCAN IP, which it presumably then proxies to the actual Oracle server. Wireshark reveals that when ODP.Net tries to connect, SCAN replies with a redirect to the actual IP of the back-end server, which IP is not routable.

I'm looking for advice on how to get ODP.Net to enjoy the behavior that SCAN is offering SQL Developer.

I attempted to use the same connection string, completely bypassing tnsnames.ora for simplicity. In SQL Developer, I configured a connection using just IP address, port and service name. I then used wireshark to observe the connection string that SQL Developer sent to the server (yes, SQL Dev repeats the CID section):

```
(DESCRIPTION=
  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.130.X.Y)(PORT=1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA=
    (CID=(PROGRAM=SQL Developer)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=myusername))
    (SERVICE_NAME=myservice)
    (CID=(PROGRAM=SQL Developer)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=myusername))))
```

I plugged this same connection string into an `OracleConnection`

```
        var bldr = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
        bldr.DataSource = @"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.130.X.Y)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=SQL Developer)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=myusername))(SERVICE_NAME=myservice)(CID=(PROGRAM=SQL Developer)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=myuser))))";
        var connection = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(bldr.ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        connection.Close();
```

And instead of connecting I receive a timeout. Further examination of captured packets reveals the behavior detailed above: SCAN acts as a proxy for SQL Developer but not for ODP.

Comment: Compare the connect string you are using with SQL Developer to what you are using with .NET. If you use the exact same connect info, the behavior should be the same.

Comment: @ChristianShay thanks very much for the reply. That's exactly what I thought too! I couldn't get it to work, though. I added some detail about what I tried to the question. Does anything catch your eye? Thanks again.

Comment: A few comments: Instead of using OracleConnectionStringBuilder, just use the actual literal connection string to take one more moving part out of the equation for the time being. Likewise, instead of using the TNS entry, using EZ Connect instead in both SQL Developer and in ODP,NET.. something like 10.130.X.Y:1521/myservice  Make sure this string works with SQL Developer before you try with ODP.NET.